# Как оптимизировать алгоритм сравнения элементов двух массивов?

Tags: pascal

Как можно оптимизировать алгоритм?

```
procedure E(n, m: integer; A, B: tMatrix; var C: tMatrix);
var i, j: integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=1 to m do begin
      if i<=j then C[i,j]:=A[i,j] + B[i,j] else C[i,j]:=A[i,j] - B[i,j];
    end;
end;
```

На вход подаются три матрицы. И в зависимости от условия (`i<=j` или `i>j`) создаётся третья матрица.

Comment: Откуда у тебя проблемы в производительности, матрицы размером 10000 на 10000 ?

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант убрать ветвление:

```
  for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=1 to m do
      C[i,j]:=A[i,j] + B[i,j] * Ord(i<=j) - B[i,j] * Ord(i>j);
```

Второй вариант убрать ветвление:

```
  for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=i to m do
      C[i,j]:=A[i,j] + B[i,j];


  for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=1 to i - 1 do
      C[i,j]:=A[i,j] - B[i,j];
```

Проверяй!